# Azure Dev Ops : Restart automatically build policy when build expired

Tags: build, azure-devops

When I configure a build Policy on a specific branch, the pull request can failed if the build expired (ex : target branch updated).
Is there a way to restart automatically the build for this pull request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the default behavior as long as auto-complete is set and all other policy requirements are met.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365605/automatically-start-expired-pull-request-build-on.html

Comment: Ok I need to configure Autocomplete. But there is a limitation by design : 1 restart max.